# Pandas: Write to Excel not working in Databricks

Tags: python, pandas, databricks, azure-databricks, xlsxwriter

I was trying to convert parquet file to excel file. However, when I am trying to do so, using pandas or **openpyxl** engine, it is showing "`Operation not supported`" error. However, I can read excel file using **openpyxl** engine in databricks.

While Reading the below code is working:

```
xlfile = '/dbfs/mnt/raw/BOMFILE.xlsx'
tmp_csv = '/dbfs/mnt/trusted/BOMFILE.csv'
pdf = pd.DataFrame(pd.read_excel(xlfile, engine='openpyxl'))
pdf.to_csv (tmp_csv, index = None, header=True)
```

However, when I tried to write the same using openpyxl as well as xlswriter, it is not working:

```
parq = '/mnt/raw/PRODUCT.parquet'
final = '/dbfs/mnt/trusted/PRODUCT.xlsx'
df = spark.read.format("parquet").option("header", "true").load(parq)
pandas_df = df.toPandas()
pandas_df.to_excel(final, engine='openpyxl')
#pandas_df.to_excel(outfile, engine='xlsxwriter')#, sheet_name=tbl)
```

**Error I got:**

```
FileCreateError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported

OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
FileCreateError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-473603709964454> in <module>
     17       final = '/dbfs/mnt/trusted/PRODUCT.xlsx'
     18       print(outfile)
---> 19       pandas_df.to_excel(outfile, engine='openpyxl')
     20       #pandas_df.to_excel(outfile, engine='xlsxwriter')#, sheet_name=tbl)

/databricks/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in to_excel(self, excel_writer, sheet_name, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, startrow, startcol, engine, merge_cells, encoding, inf_rep, verbose, freeze_panes)
   2179             startcol=startcol,
   2180             freeze_panes=freeze_panes,
-> 2181             engine=engine,
   2182         )
   2183
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem is that there are [limitations](https://docs.databricks.com/data/databricks-file-system.html#local-file-api-limitations) when it comes to the local file API support in DBFS (the `/dbfs` fuse).  For example, it doesn't support random writes that are required for Excel files.  From documentation:

> Does not support random writes. For workloads that require random writes, perform the I/O on local disk first and then copy the result to /dbfs.

In your case it could be:

```py
from shutil import copyfile

parq = '/mnt/raw/PRODUCT.parquet'
final = '/dbfs/mnt/trusted/PRODUCT.xlsx'
temp_file = '/tmp/PRODUCT.xlsx'
df = spark.read.format("parquet").option("header", "true").load(parq)
pandas_df = df.toPandas()
pandas_df.to_excel(temp_file, engine='openpyxl')

copyfile(temp_file, final)
```

P.S. You can also use `dbutils.fs.cp` to copy file ([doc](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html)) - it will also work on Community Edition where the `/dbfs` isn't supported

Comment: Thanks for that. This came up in the XlsxWriter [issues](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues/705) as well. Do you know what is meant by "random writes" in those docs?

Comment: Random means that data isn't written sequentially.  For example we wrote some bytes, then rewind to earlier position and wrote new bytes. For excel it's quite common pattern

Comment: Thanks. That should have been obvious but I wasn't sure if that was what was meant because XlsxWriter doesn't use any random writes (although it does use random reads of a sort with rewind()). I guess the issue is with zipfile.py which probably does have random writes. The full stack trace isn't shown above but in the issue I linked to the exception is thrown in zipfile.py around a file seek(). Anyway thanks for the link. It is good to know that the workaround is officially documented.

Comment: yes, writing zipfile usually requires random seek because you need to update some offsets after you finished writing data. It's possible to do it in one pass, but it's use-case specific