# Databricks error while saving file in excel format : OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported

Tags: python, excel, dataframe, databricks, azure-databricks

Hi i am trying to save a dataframe file in a excel format. But keeps getting this error
OSError: [Errno 95] Operation not supported
i am trying with the following code :

```
  filtered_df.to_excel('/dbfs/digital_nurture_abovejune.xlsx',index=False)
  dbutils.fs.cp('dbfs:/digital_nurture_abovejune.xlsx', path + 'output')
```

the snippet of error is:

```
 OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)

  filtered_df.to_excel('/dbfs/digital_nurture_abovejune.xlsx',index=False)
  2 dbutils.fs.cp('dbfs:/digital_nurture_abovejune.xlsx', path + 'output')

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in to_excel(self, 
excel_writer, sheet_name, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, startrow, 
startcol, engine, merge_cells, encoding, inf_rep, verbose, freeze_panes, storage_options)
 2187             inf_rep=inf_rep,
 2188         )
 -> 2189         formatter.write(
 2190             excel_writer,
2191             sheet_name=sheet_name,

 /databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/excel.py in write(self, writer, sheet_name, startrow, startcol, freeze_panes, engine, storage_options)
829             # make sure to close opened file handles
830             if need_save:
 --> 831                 writer.close()
```

Comment: are you using free community edition?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas: Write to Excel not working in Databricks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67471958/pandas-write-to-excel-not-working-in-databricks)

Comment: This is known issue, see the linked answer