# Databricks df.toPandas().toCsv() save failed due to [Errno 95] Operation not supported

Tags: python, pandas, azure, databricks

As the title says, we are getting an intermittent error when saving out csv files in databricks by using the following command:

```
df.toPandas().to_csv(f"/dbfs{saveMountName}/{Year}/{Month}/{Message}{Day}.csv", header=True, index=False)
```

This command works for smaller DFs, however a few of the dfs we want to save out are 100k rows or more.

We then get this error when we try to save out the files:

```
[Errno 95] Operation not supported
```

Anyone got any ideas what is causing this? As the online documentation isn't great on it.

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure that the directory you are trying to save the file to exists and has enough space to accommodate the file you are trying to save.

Comment: Does the error occur in the `.toPandas()` call, or in the pandas `.to_csv()` call?

Answer (score 0):

As per the Official [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/dbfs/errno95-operation-not-supported),

> Direct appends and random writes are not supported in FUSE v2, from databricks 6.0 and above.

The workaround can be, first write the file to a databricks local disk and then copy or move to the mount location using `dbutils.fs.mv()` or `dbutils.fs.cp()`.

Follow the similar [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67471958/pandas-write-to-excel-not-working-in-databricks) by **@Alex OTT** to understand more.

**AFAIK**, In case of large dataframes, saving to files using pandas might not be a good option as our driver node should have enough RAM for total large dataframe, otherwise it will crash our driver node.

For large dataframes, saving to files using Pyspark might be the better option. Use `coalesce(1)` for that. but it will give a random name for the output file with two extra files. To get a single file with a required name, you can go through this [tutorial](https://analyticjeremy.github.io/Databricks_Examples/Write%20to%20a%20Single%20CSV%20File) by **@analyticjeremy**.