# Azure databricks: Handling Excel Templates in Python, Including Charts and Formulas

Tags: python, azure, charts, azure-databricks

I'm currently working on a project in Azure databricks where I need to automate tasks involving Excel templates in Python. Previously, in a Windows environment, I used a combination of openpyxl for basic Excel operations and the Dispatch from win32com.client library for more advanced tasks like copying charts sheets and adjust links.

Now, I'm transitioning to an Azure environment and facing challenges in replicating the same workflow. Specifically, I need to:

Open an Excel template file.
Write data to specific sheets.
Manipulate charts based on formulas that depend on calculations and newly added data.
I'm aware that using data_only=True in openpyxl depends on the provenance of the file, and it may not always work as expected.

Has anyone encountered a similar scenario or have suggestions on how to approach this in an Azure environment ( reset_charts_orig function below)? Any insights or alternative libraries would be greatly appreciated.

def reset_charts_orig(orig, new):
"""
:param orig: input path
:param new: output path
"""
path1 = os.path.abspath(orig)
path2 = os.path.abspath(new)

```
xl = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.Visible = False

wb1 = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=path1)
wb2 = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=path2)

ws1 = wb1.Worksheets('GrafikenJahre')
ws1.Copy(Before=wb2.Worksheets('GLM'))

wb2.ChangeLink(Name=path1, NewName=path2, Type=1)
wb2.Close(SaveChanges=True)
wb1.Close(SaveChanges=False)
xl.Quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Databricks clusters are using the `Linux`, so you can't use `pywin32`  which is supported only in Microsoft Windows, because you can access the Win32 API only from Windows.

Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/918741/not-able-to-install-pywin32-or-pypiwin32-on-databr) for more information.

So you can use `openpyxl` for adding charts and manipulating.
Below is the example of adding chart.

Data in excel.

| 0 | First Name | Last Name | Gender | Country | Age | Date | Id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Dulce | Abril | Female | United States | 32 | 15/10/2017 | 1562 |
| 2 | Mara | Hashimoto | Female | Great Britain | 25 | 16/08/2016 | 1582 |
| 3 | Philip | Gent | Male | France | 36 | 21/05/2015 | 2587 |
| 4 | Kathleen | Hanner | Female | United States | 25 | 15/10/2017 | 3549 |
| 5 | Nereida | Magwood | Female | United States | 58 | 16/08/2016 | 2468 |
| 6 | Gaston | Brumm | Male | United States | 24 | 21/05/2015 | 2554 |
| 7 | Etta | Hurn | Female | Great Britain | 56 | 15/10/2017 | 3598 |
| 8 | Earlean | Melgar | Female | United States | 27 | 16/08/2016 | 2456 |
| 9 | Vincenza | Weiland | Female | United States | 40 | 21/05/2015 | 6548 |

Code :

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference

with open("/dbfs/FileStore/tables/file_example_XLS_10.xlsx", 'rb') as f:
    workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(f)

worksheet = workbook['Sheet1']

chart = BarChart()

data = Reference(worksheet, min_col=6, min_row=2, max_col=6, max_row=11)  # Age column
categories = Reference(worksheet, min_col=5, min_row=2, max_col=5, max_row=11)  # Country column

chart.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
chart.set_categories(categories)

worksheet.add_chart(chart, "A12")

workbook.save("/tmp/file_example_XLS_10.xlsx")

dbutils.fs.cp("file:/tmp/file_example_XLS_10.xlsx","/mnt/jgsblob/from_databricks/sample.xlsx")
```

Here, make sure you giving path as per dbfs filesystem while reading file.
But while saving `workbook.save('/dbfs/')` doesn't work due to limitations with local API support.
So, save it temporarily in local filesystem and copy it to dbfs or mounted storage account using `dbutils.fs.cp`.
Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67471958/pandas-write-to-excel-not-working-in-databricks) solution for more about this.

Output :

[image]